# Has anyone had any luck compiling this .NET binding for Mapnik?

Tags: c++, binding, mapnik

So I'm trying to build this library that is a .NET binding for Mapnik http://mapnik.org.
I ran the "../ext/install.cmd" file successfully but I think that only builds
the boost library for c++. When I run the visual studio solution for it afterwards it still has like 900 errors!
Mostly in 1 class for text rendering.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mapniknet/

I would love to use this library if anyone can help me get the build to run succesfully.

My system:
Win7 64bit

Comment: There isn't much in your question to work off of.

Comment: Please ask a real, answerable question. Do you have a concrete problem?

Comment: I updated the question with what the binding is for. I just need help getting it built from source since they don't offer a pre-compiled dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems older than Windows 7 patching can not be run if there are spaces in "Program Files" folder name.
You can patch mapnik and ICU sources manually applying Mapnik.patch on MapNik folder and icu_vs2010.patch on icu one.
If sources were changed previously they should be reverted before patching.
After patching rerun install.cmd

Comment: There a couple problems with the install.cmd and apply_patch.cmd. Even on Win7 machines, when running batch commands, you need to surround any path with spaces with double quotes. So the patches weren't running. I got the patches to run. I then tried running the build on the solution again and still got errors. Is there anyway you can just post the dlls?

Comment: I uploaded dlls of the latest revision. You can get them from Downloads section.

Comment: I thought this was a managed dll. It won't let me add it as a reference. Do I need to use [DllImport("mapnik_c.dll")] to add it?

Comment: mapnik_c.dll is used by .Net wrapper MapnikCs. It can be compiled from sources without any C++ errors. Missing .dll will be added into archive.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me to get this to work. Your project is awesome!!!! I hope you keep working on it and I will spread the word about it.